# Dependency injection - Nested objects

Tags: object-oriented, php, dependency-injection

**# Introduction**

I am working on a CMS application in PHP with about 200 classes.
The CMS, in general, does the same thing every CMS does: generate sites.

I am learning a lot about OOP and design patterns and only recently started learning about how to create maintainable code using Dependency Injection.

The issue is that I don't know how to solve the issues I currently have and with which design pattern.

**# Possible solutions**

I have read of the following (possible) solutions:

- Service Provides
- Dependency Injection Containers
- Factory Classes
- Dependency Injection
- Etc...

All the solutions seem to have advantages and disadvantages, but the more I read about them, the more difficulties I have choosing one.

**# The problem**

The biggest issue is needing stateful dependency, like `page` or `site` which contain data loaded from the database, in an object nested inside other classes.

To explain this further, I think it is best to show you an example.
The flow of the system is something like this:

1. Every request is redirected to the index.php file using the rewrite module of Apache
2. The `index.php` script initiates the `app class` and calls the function `start_app()`
3. The `start_app()` function dissects the URL and uses `GET/POST` variables to generate a route to a certain page
4. Every dependency that is loaded is contained in a `dependencyLoader`
5. When all dependencies are loaded, a template file is parsed and each line is checked for specific tags (e.g. `<!-- CSS-FILE --!>`) and data from the dependencies is then rendered into HTML and placed instead of the tag.
6. If a tag is found, the dependencies are asked if it contains data for this specific tag and will return specific objects that render their data in a unique way. E.g. objects like 'phpInclude', 'cssFile', 'element', 'metaData' etc..

The app class looks something like this (simplified):

```
     class app {

        protected $dependencyContainer;

        function __construct() {
            $this->dependencyContainer = new dependencyContainer();
        }

        public function start_app() {

            // Load in navigator that contains routing information
            $this->dependencyContainer->set('navigator', new navigator($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));

            // Load site data 
            $domainController = new domainController();
            $site = $domainController->loadSite($this->dependencyContainer->get('navigator'));
            $this->dependencyContainer->set('site', $site);

            $pageController = new pageController();
            $page = $pageController->loadPage($this->dependencyContainer->get('navigator'));
            $this->dependencyContainer->set('page', $page);

            // Etc...
            // Etc...

            $templatePath = $site->getTemplate();
            $this->renderDocument($templatePath);
        }

        private function renderDocument($templatePath) {       
            $template = file_get_contents($templatePath);

            $lines = explode("\n", $template);

            foreach($lines as $line) {                    
                // If a tag is found, the dependencies are asked if it contains data for this 
                if($tag = $this->filter($line)) {
                    $fragments = $this->dependencyContainer->output($tag);

                    foreach($fragment as $fragment) {
                        if($fragment->needDependencies()) {
                            $fragment->render($this->dependencyContainer);
                        } else {
                            $fragment->render();
                        }
                    }
                // Process lines, echo the ones that are plain HTML
                } else {
                    echo $line;
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

The returned objects (fragments) can be of two types:

```
elementFragment {
     protected $data;
     const needDependencies = false;

     public render() {
          // Render logic here
          return 'SOME HTML';
     }
}

dependencyFragment {
     protected $data;
     const needDependencies = true;

     public render($dependencies) {
          if($dependecies->has('page')) $page = $dependencies->get('page');
          if($dependecies->has('site')) $site = $dependencies->get('site');
          // Etc etc etc etc etc

          // Logic to generate HTML here
          // E.g the phpInclude fragments has logic like this:
          return include __PATH__ . $this->data;
     }
}
```

The issue arises when I have another level of objects inside the `dependencyFragment` object. This is sadly a common situation.

**# Questions**

- Do I keep pushing the `dependencyContainer` into every function call or object constructor?
- Or maybe a (static) singleton pattern is a better solution to house the dependencies and make them available?